# Saving GridView cell value in a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, null, nullreferenceexception

I want to save GridView cells in a list to compare it with another list.

This is what I tried:

```
        BudgetCommessa budgetCommessa = new BudgetCommessa();
        List<BudgetCommessa> listaDaGridView = new List<BudgetCommessa>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= preventivoView.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            budgetCommessa.Task = Convert.ToString(preventivoView.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text);//SelectedDataKey.Values[0]);
            listaDaGridView.Add(budgetCommessa);
        }
```

but i get a NullReferenceException even if the cell (0,0) of the GridView is populated

Comment: This is for a single cell, if it will work fine, i will implement other cells

Comment: Put a debug point at the line which you call `Convert.ToString()`, hover over `SelectedRow` or in your imediate window type `?preventivoView.SelectedRow`

Comment: @LukeHennerley it says "null", but i really don't understand why, this is a huge populated gridview with no null values

Comment: Although you have much data, you may not have been able to select a single row. This will be down to you not having a `Select` column on the gridview itself which a user can click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if your gridview has any selected row. Apart from that, there are other  problems in your code:

1. Loop should start with 0 and should continue with `Rows.Count - 1`.
2. You should instantiate `budgetCommesa` inside the for loop, otherwise you will end up with a list of object all pointing to the same value.

So your code should be like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < preventivoView.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
        if(preventivoView.SelectedRow != null)
            {            
            BudgetCommessa budgetCommessa = new BudgetCommessa();
            budgetCommessa.Task = Convert.ToString(preventivoView.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text);//SelectedDataKey.Values[0]);
            listaDaGridView.Add(budgetCommessa);
            }
 }
```

If you are looking to get value from a cell from all rows, irrespective of selected then, you have to **iterate each Row, instead of SelectedRow**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < preventivoView.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
    BudgetCommessa budgetCommessa = new BudgetCommessa();
    budgetCommessa.Task = Convert.ToString(preventivoView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text);//SelectedDataKey.Values[0]);
    listaDaGridView.Add(budgetCommessa);
 }
```

Comment: +1 for the code advice, but it doesn't exactly solve his problem :)

Comment: @user1711154, check the edited answer, I believe you are trying to iterate each row , instead of SelectedRow.

Comment: @LukeHennerley, I can only guess what is going wrong. I believe the OP is trying to iterate each row, instead of SelectedRow, that is what I have put in my edited answer

Comment: Yes, i made a mistake because of my awful English, sorry everybody. @Habib you made my day. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
    budgetCommessa.Task = preventivoView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;
```

hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a selected row, then you need a button field in your grid.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedRow_changed">
    <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Select" HeaderText="Select Row"
            Text="Select" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then have an event for the selected row changed.

```
public void SelectedRow_Changed(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
  GridViewRow row = CustomersGridView.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];
  BudgetCommessa budgetCommessa = new BudgetCommessa();
  //Would of shifted one because of the new button column
  budgetCommessa.Task = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Text);
}
```

If you want to refer to each row and iterate through them, use Habib's answer as that is correct.